# Shared x axis on six iterated subplots

Tags: matplotlib, axis, axis-labels, subplot

here is the graph i have so far:

[image: graph]

I want to have a shared x and y axis.

I'm trying to get a shared x and y axis for six subplots, which i iterate over in a for loop. I want to show frequency on the y, and then gamma radiation on the x.

```
elems=[island1,island2,island3,island4,island5,island6,island7]

#these elems are radiation data pulled in from excel

fig,axtemp=plt.subplots(2,3) 
fig.set_size_inches(15,15) 
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2)
props=dict(boxstyle='round',facecolor='white',alpha=0.5)
colors=['red','green','darkorange','mediumblue','gold','purple']
for i,elem in enumerate(elems):
    ax=axtemp[i%2][i/2]
    bins = 10**(np.linspace(0.1,4))
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.set_xlim([3.5,1000])
    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(elem, bins=bins, normed=1, color=colors[i], alpha=0.75)
ax.set_xlabel('Gamma Radiation, mrem/yr')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyplot allows to set the shared axis e.g. directly in the call to [`plt.subplots`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots)

In your case simply use

```
fig,axtemp=plt.subplots(2,3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

you would then only set the scale and axis limits to one of the plots.